# What http header should be used if the server does not accept the request to upgrade?

Tags: http, http-headers

If the client wants to negotiate a change in the protocol, it does so through the `upgrade` http header, perhaps like so:

```
Upgrade:  TLS/1.0
```

If the server is willing to upgrade, it responds with a `101 status code` and the `upgrade` header, perhaps like so:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade:  TLS/1.0, HTTP/1.1
```

But what if the server is unwilling or unable to upgrade?  What status code does it reply with?  And what headers does it send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ignores the request to upgrade and responds as if the `Upgrade` field was not present in the request, so the requested resource is returned.

Comment: Is this what the spec says, what browsers tend to do, or what?

Comment: @james.garriss it's what the spec says and what conforming servers do. Not sure why browsers are relevant here as this is about server behavior.

Comment: Yep, shoulda said "server" not "browser."  My bad.

Comment: So here's section 14.42 in the HTTP 1.1 spec.  As far as I can tell, it doesn't say how the server should respond if it won't upgrade.  Maybe that's in a different part of the spec?  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.42

Comment: I have found another doc, RFC 2817, which is more clear. It says (in 3.1), "In this case, the server MAY respond to the clear HTTP operation normally, OR switch to secured operation."   http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2817.txt  But this spec is about upgrading to TLS, so I'm uncertain if it's applicable to all upgrades.

Comment: The server either upgrades, and says so in a 101 message, or does not. If it does not, it responds to the request as-is. I think that's pretty clear.

Comment: Think about it this way: the client might be talking to an HTTP 1.0 server that does not know about Upgrade at all and thus ignores the field. As the spec certainly does not declare all old servers non-conforming, it is allowed to ignore Upgrade requests.